# Not able to reopen a browser in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

My Intention is to run function x() 10 times.

It runs for the first time >> data is saved in the file >> browser is closed. Then, the browser reopens >> function x() is run again >> data is saved to file. Repeat a total of 10 times.

Function x() is making accounts on a website with random details and saving it to a .txt file

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path")
def x():
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[contains(@class,'38oWvQ')])[5]").click()
with open('Accounts.txt','a') as f:
    f.write("Writing something" + '\n')
    f.close()

driver.quit()

for i in range(10):
  x()
```

The function is running smoothly with no bugs, but when the browser is closed after the first time it will not reopen and is throwing the error below:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /session/0336bf272a906951c3f88ed14ec69e63/url
 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0
0000063EF922130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No conn
ection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

How do I resolve this? Or is there another way to do this? Kindly let me know that too. Thanks.

Comment: Well the error says it all. The website has some limit on the number of connections it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing `time.sleep()` from 1 second to at least 30 second
since you are using a loop to call the function, put time.sleep before you call `driver.get()`

Comment: Hi i was able to figure that out myself and added the sleep before driver, but forgot to update here
Thanks a bunch for answering anyway :)

Comment: if my answer helped, pls mark it as accepted . thanks @ShantanuRauthan

Comment: how would i do that cant see the option , i upvoted btw @anti_cse51